# Securely passing parameters to EJB from servlet?

Tags: java, ejb, parameter-passing

**What is the secure, canonical means for passing multiple HTTP parameters from a servlet to an EJB?** The application is a web-based SMTP client which takes the following parameters:

- From
- To
- BCC
- CC
- Subject
- Body

In an effort to keep the *model* (`EJB`) separate from the *view* (`JSP`) and *controller* (`servlet`), **I'd like to refrain from passing an** `HttpServletRequest` **directly to the** `EJB`.

- Should I use a `Session` variable?
- Should I pass 6 parameters? To pass the 6 parameters, I'd have to perform business logic in the control-tier.

Code:

```
 public String send_message(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);

        String from = request.getParameter("from");
        String to = request.getParameter("to");
        String cc = request.getParameter("cc");
        String bcc = request.getParameter("bcc");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String body = request.getParameter("body");

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);             
        Address sender = new InternetAddress(from);
        message.setFrom(sender);

        Address[] toAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(to);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);

        Address[] ccAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(cc);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddresses);

        Address[] bccAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(bcc);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddresses);

        message.setSubject(subject);                
        message.setText(body);  

        Transport.send(message);
        return "Your message was sent successfully!";
    } catch (AddressException AE){
        return "Oops! There was an error parsing the addresses!";
    } catch (SendFailedException SFE){
        return "Oops! There was an error sending the message!";
    } catch (MessagingException ME){
        return "Oops! There was an error sending the message!"; 
    }
}
```

### Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't want to be destructive, but if you are learning jsp you should consider that this is a deprecated technology in favour of JSF

Comment: Transitioning to modern technology is not an option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to refrain from passing an HttpServletRequest directly to the EJB.

Very good. HttpServletRequest belongs to the web layer and should never be passed to business layers.

> Should I use a Session variable?

That's not a good idea, for the same reason. Session also belongs to servlet layer. Besides, in a well designed application it might not be possible at all; web components depend on EJB components, not the other way round. Using session in EJBs would mean reversing this relation.

> Should I pass 6 parameters? To pass the 6 parameters, I'd have to perform business logic in the control-tier.

Six parameters are quite close to "a lot", if not already. Personally, I'd qualify this situation as worth introducing a new parameter object (a.k.a. value object, a.k.a. transfer object) holding these values. Especially when you write a new code, it would be a sin to design a method that has 6 parameters defining the same concept — a mail. Multiple-parameter methods are hard to read and are prone to "broken window effect" — encourage adding yet another parameter when extensions are needed.

> To pass the 6 parameters, I'd have to perform business logic in the control-tier.

Think of it as adapting one representation to another — it's not business logic. BL is what's directly influenced by your requirements, what you're doing here it's just architecture.

Comment: So, I should create a POJO to parse the HTTPServletRequest? Or should I parse the HTTPServletRequest in the servlet? Creating a POJO, or a secondary EJB to parse 6 parameters seems excessive as well.

Comment: If parsing is just obtaining parameters from `request`, I'd leave it in the servlet; if it's complicated, I'd probably create a transformer class to do this. I meant creating a POJO to **pass** six parameters from servlet to EJB, not for parsing them (please google for "transfer object" or "value object" EJB design pattern).